# ASP.NET inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts, tags

I'm trying to get some ASP working with some javascript that renders a chart depending on the info you provide.

I'm talking about [this](http://jsbin.com/ukaxod/144/embed?javascript,live)

```
 <div id="chart"></div>

 <script>
 new Morris.Donut({

        element: 'chart',

        data: [
           @{
                foreach(Tuple<int, int> party in ViewBag.parties)
                {

                    @: { label: '@PartyModel.Entity.getNameByID("par:" + party.Item1)', value: '@party.Item2' },

                }
            }
        ],
        labelColor: '#666',
        colors: [
          '#c54743',
          '#2868b0',
          '#ffae00',
          '#c65cbb',
          '#79d09a',
          '#15a5e1',
          '#c7c66a',
          '#69a85c'
        ],
    });
</script>
```

It works perfectly fine on it's own.

I also tried wrapping "text" around it..

```
<text>
{ label: '@PartyModel.Entity.getNameByID("par:" + party.Item1)', value:'@party.Item2' },
</text>
```

Did not work either.

Comment: Is this an MVC view or WebForms or clasic ASP, your question doesn't make it clear. I'm guessing MVC

Comment: It's MVC. My bad for not making that clear.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? Are there any errors? What is the HTML that this outputs?

Comment: As you can see here http://jsbin.com/ukaxod/144/embed?javascript,live the output should be a chart in the div with the ID "chart". However, it does not output anything.

Comment: So if you load the page in a browser and view the source, there's nothing? I find that hard to fathom!!

Comment: You can see here http://prntscr.com/2zy2t1 that the "label" is not being parsed, leaving it blank of any info.

Comment: Put a break point in your view and debug it, should be able to check that you've actually got data in your model?

Comment: See my former comment.